# How to insert values in postgresql table by a python function and Psycopg?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a postgresql function in order to insert values that works fine in psql

```
CREATE FUNCTION new_msg(p1 type, p2 type)
 RETURNS type AS
BEGIN
 -- some logic
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) values (p1,p2);
return value;
END;
LANGUAGE language_name;
```

A python function like ...

```
import psycopg2
from config import config
def new_msg(ref_p1, ref_p2):
   # Configuracion
    params = config()
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from new_msg(%s,%s);",(ref_p1, ref_p1,))
```

But when the functions is called in python

```
new_msg(some_p1,some_p2)
```

the values are not inserted into the corresponding table and a error is not  generated. I also tried callproc method from Psycopg2 is not working. Any suggestion? thanks.

Comment: You need to commit the changes.  There is little to go on to help you though as the code you provide is obviously not anything working.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You need to commit your changes. You can try add cur.commit() after your code to do it every time you write to the DB, or you could try using a context manager to handle it all.

Create a file called mydb.py

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.pool
from contextlib import contextmanager

dbpool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(host=<<YourHost>>,
                                              port=<<YourPort>>,
                                              dbname=<<YourDB>>,
                                              user=<<YourUser>>,
                                              password=<<YourPassword>>,
                                              )

@contextmanager
def db_cursor():
    conn = dbpool.getconn()
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            yield cur
            conn.commit()
    except:
        conn.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        dbpool.putconn(conn)
```

Then your code can use:

```
import mydb

def new_msg(ref_p1, ref_p2):
    with mydb.db_cursor as cur:
    cur.execute("""
                   select * from new_msg(%(ref_p1)s,%(ref_p2)s)
                """, {
                      'ref_p1': ref_p1,
                      'ref_p2': ref_p2,
                      }
               )

    return
```

Comment: why, do you need commit changes after select statement?